# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android application with my JNI libraries

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am making an application that uses some JNI libraries built for an another app. I have, of course, imported all the necessary Java calsses to my application while keeping the package names the same. I have two libraries imported:

- **libopencv_java3.so**
- **libopencv_xfeatures2d.so** (I built this for an another project)

When I go into my old application, all the libraries load fine, but in this one I do not get any errors regardin loading the libaries themselves, but i only get errors regarding the acutal methods. This happens only with my library, as all **opencv_java3** calls seem to work fine. I have placed all of the **.so** files in the *jniLibs* folder, and I checked the apk to see if they were packaged correctly, and everything seems fine there. Anybody else having my same issue?

**BTW** I am using Android Studio 1.5.1, libraries built with NDK r10 with target API 15 (which is also the minimum API for the application).

Comment: have you called System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");

Comment: Yup. And also called "opencv_xfeatures2d"